# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException on File.Delete for a valid path

Tags: c#, file, exception, directory, max-path

I wrote code to delete a folder with all its structure recursively.

I got `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` on `File.Delete` for a valid filename that I got from `Directory.GetFiles(path)`. I added `File.Exists` before and it tells me that the file does not exists either of I can see it in Explorer.

I know I can do it with `SHFileOperation` which should work fine. But I would like to use native C# (no direct Windows API).

I red: [.NET 4.6.2 and long paths on Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/) and set enable "Enable Win 32 long paths" in local group policy editor.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Does anyone can tell me what's wrong in my code? Or what I can do to make it works?

The path in error is:

> 'E:\CobianBackupOld\cn1629\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\AppIconCache\100\{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}_Microsoft Visual Studio 9_0_Application_PreEmptive Solutions_Dotfuscator Community Edition_dotfuscator_exe'

I'm the owner of that file (I do have privilege to delete it).

> **UPDATE**
>
> I partly fixed my error but would like to know how to fix it properly (Recent frameworks are suppose to support long path???).
> My actual fix is to add that code at start of my recursive function
>
> ```
> if (path.Length < 2 || !path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
> {
>   path = @"\\?\" + path;
> }
> ```
>
> **UPDATE 2**  Although not directly related... Just want to bring an important point, C# File.Delete or Directory.Delete does NOT delete
> readonly file or folder, you should also change their permissions to
> normal before deleting them, otherwise you get an access denied error.

FYI, my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HQ.Util.General.IO
{
    public class DirectoryRemoverRecursive
    {
        private readonly Action<string, string> _pathStatus;
        private readonly Func<string, bool> _callbackCanRemoveFile;
        private readonly Func<string, bool> _callbackCanRemoveFolder;
        private Func<bool> _shouldCancel;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathStatus">Arguments are [path] and [null on success or exception message]</param>
        /// <param name="callbackCanRemoveFile">Argument is path and should return true to delete. If this function is null, all path will be deleted.</param>
        /// <param name="callbackCanRemoveFolder">Argument is path and should return true to delete. If this function is null, all path will be deleted.</param>
        /// <param name="shouldCancel">If null will never cancel. Cancel when func return true</param>
        public DirectoryRemoverRecursive(
            Action<string, string> pathStatus = null, 
            Func<string, bool> callbackCanRemoveFile = null, 
            Func<string, bool> callbackCanRemoveFolder = null, 
            Func<bool> shouldCancel = null)
        {
            _pathStatus = pathStatus;
            _callbackCanRemoveFile = callbackCanRemoveFile;
            _callbackCanRemoveFolder = callbackCanRemoveFolder;
            _shouldCancel = shouldCancel;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// return true if canceled
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Remove(string path)
        {
            string result = null;

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    if (_shouldCancel != null)
                    {
                        if (_shouldCancel())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Remove(subDir))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                    if (_shouldCancel != null)
                    {
                        if (_shouldCancel())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Remove(filename))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    if (_callbackCanRemoveFolder != null)
                    {
                        if (!_callbackCanRemoveFolder(path))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    Directory.Delete(path);
                    result = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        if (_callbackCanRemoveFile != null)
                        {
                            if (!_callbackCanRemoveFile(path))
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        File.Delete(path);
                        result = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Print($"File does not exists {path}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.Message;
                }
            }

            _pathStatus?.Invoke(path, result);

            return false;
        }

        // ******************************************************************

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although no as perfect as I would have wished, I fixed my bugs by using prefix "\?\" and by ensuring that attributes are set to normal prior to delete.

I still don't undertsand why I still have to do that??? Why it is still not fixed in recent .net library?

Final code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace HQ.Util.General.IO
{
    public class DirectoryRemoverRecursive
    {
        private readonly Action<string, string, int> _pathStatus;
        private readonly Func<string, bool> _callbackCanRemoveFile;
        private readonly Func<string, bool> _callbackCanRemoveFolder;
        private Func<bool> _shouldCancel;

        public int Count { get; private set; } = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathStatus">Arguments are [path] and [null on success or exception message]</param>
        /// <param name="callbackCanRemoveFile">Argument is path and should return true to delete. If this function is null, all path will be deleted.</param>
        /// <param name="callbackCanRemoveFolder">Argument is path and should return true to delete. If this function is null, all path will be deleted.</param>
        /// <param name="shouldCancel">If null will never cancel. Cancel when func return true</param>
        public DirectoryRemoverRecursive(
            Action<string, string, int> pathStatus = null, 
            Func<string, bool> callbackCanRemoveFile = null, 
            Func<string, bool> callbackCanRemoveFolder = null, 
            Func<bool> shouldCancel = null)
        {
            _pathStatus = pathStatus;
            _callbackCanRemoveFile = callbackCanRemoveFile;
            _callbackCanRemoveFolder = callbackCanRemoveFolder;
            _shouldCancel = shouldCancel;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// return true if canceled
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Remove(string path)
        {
            string result = null;

            if (path.Length < 2 || !path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
            {
                path = @"\\?\" + path;
            }

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    if (_shouldCancel != null)
                    {
                        if (_shouldCancel())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Remove(subDir))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                    if (_shouldCancel != null)
                    {
                        if (_shouldCancel())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Remove(filename))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    if (_callbackCanRemoveFolder != null)
                    {
                        if (!_callbackCanRemoveFolder(path))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    Directory.Delete(path);
                    Count++;
                    result = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        Directory.Delete(path);
                        Count++;
                        result = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        result = "Try to delete directory exception: " + ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        if (_callbackCanRemoveFile != null)
                        {
                            if (!_callbackCanRemoveFile(path))
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        File.Delete(path);
                        Count++;
                        result = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Print($"File does not exists {path}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Delete(path);
                        Count++;
                        result = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        result = "Try to delete file exception: " + ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            _pathStatus?.Invoke(path, result, Count);

            return false;
        }

        // ******************************************************************

    }

}
```